# Hitting Probability for Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains

I have a discrete Markov Chain on the integers. From state $i$ I have a probability $\mu$ to go to $i-1$ and probability $\lambda$ to go to $i+1$, where $\mu+ \lambda=1$.

I am asked to calculate the probability that starting from $0$ we ever hit $i \ge 1$.

I tried the same approach as for the gambler ruin problem but it does not seem to work as I cannot stop at $0$.

I wrote $h(j)$ as the probability of hitting i starting from j. Then I know the following set of equations are true:

$h(i)=1$ and $h(j)=\mu h(j-1)+\lambda h(j+1)$.

However, I don't seem to find another condition to impose to get a set of solutions.

Comment: These are known as [random walks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk), and they are a well studied problem in probability.

Comment: And their indepth study is in practically every textbook on the subject.

Comment: "I tried the same approach as for the gambler ruin problem but it does not seem to work as I cannot stop at 0." If you explained what you really did, this post might become a legit question for the site.

Comment: I know i should look at h(-n) for n very large and to say that this must be zero. But i have no idea how.